# How do I call a list outside of a function in python?

Tags: python, function, call

```
def start(B):
    wordlist = []

    for w in B:
        content = w
        words = content.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:

            wordlist.append(each_word)
            print(each_word)
            return(wordlist)
```

When I call list 'wordlist' it returns that there isn't anything inside the list. How do I get the list to be callable outside of the function since it works inside the function.

[image]

EDIT: Thank you I have updated the code to reflect the mistake I was making using a print tag instead of a return tag.

Comment: https://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php

Answer (score 6):

```
def start(B):
    wordlist = []

    for w in B:
        content = w
        words = content.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:

            wordlist.append(each_word)
            print(wordlist)
    return wordlist

B=["hello bye poop"]
wordlist=start(B)
```

Just add `return wordlist` to the function. Adding a `return` statement in a function returns the object whenever the function is called appropriately and you can store that returned variable in a global scope variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'm just starting out learning python so was at a loss with what to do and most other questions seemed way more complex  and I couldn't figure out what I was missing to make my code work. So thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list that first function creates as an argument for the second function:

```
def some_list_function():
  # generates list
  return mylist

def some_other_function(mylist):
  # takes list as argument and processes
  return result

some_other_function(some_list_function())
```

You can use this in the future as reference.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will reference this in the future. I'm curious though, wouldn't I need to then run both functions for each list I have to make it work? Wouldn't that be more cumbersome?

Comment: On a larger scale, it ends up being more efficient